# TFS branch and merging

Tags: tfs

I have a project folder called as "APP1" . We are currently deploying code from this folder . we would like to create one more folder or branch so that Dev can easily checkin all their new changes without directly affecting the main folder .

Should we have one more branch of folder "APP1" so that Dev can checkin all their changes in the newly created branch and eventually we can merge all the new changes to the main folder "APP1"?

Is this a correct approach and how easy it will be for us to merge all the new changes to the main folder ?

We have team of about 4 developers working on the same project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using Basic Branch Plan. The structure like this Development <-- Main --> Release. You can branch your project "Main" into two, one named "Development", the other one named "Release". All users can work in Development branch, after they test their code, then merge to Main branch. When you want to release your project, you can merge your code from Main branch to Release branch.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response !!How easy is it in TFS to merge the changes from "Development" branch  to "Main" and from "Main" to release ?

Comment: In Source Control Explorer, right cilck the branch that you want to merge, point to Branching and Merging, and then click Merge.

Comment: Yes , I have tried that and it works great if there are few changes to be merged , but i would like to know any other complexities that we might face if we have multiples changes to be merged with more developers working on the same branch .

Comment: You may get conflicts if other team members have checked in changes between the time that you got the latest version of the file and the time that you try to check it in, but you can resolve the conflicts easily by AutoResolve, AutoMerge, or manually resolve. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181432.aspx

Comment: Thank you !! That's what i wanted to confirm .

Answer (score 0):

That would be one way to do it.  You'll likely need to play around with differing branching and merging strategies until you figure out what works for you and your team.

There's a large guide put together by the ALM rangers for TFS branching and merging strategies. See https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/

Here's a picture from one of their guides describing the potential branching/merging strategies that may work for your team, depending on team size and release cadence:

[image]